# Call 2 shell from a shell father and not exit if a shell child contain an "exit command"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

hi i have 3 shell script:

first.sh

```
#! /bin/ksh

echo "prova"
. ./second.sh
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
. ./third.sh
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

second.sh is:

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "sono nel secondo script"
exit 9
```

i can't edit second.sh. How ignore this exit 9 and continue with third.sh?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `. ./second.sh`; instead, run `./second.sh`.

Comment: Because `. ./second.sh` tells it to run all of the commands from `second.sh` **inside the current shell**, meaning that if it runs `exit`, then the current shell exits. That's what the `.` command, also called `source` in bash, does.

Comment: @user3589887, ...that said, I'd suggest setting the execute permission and using `./second.sh` instead of `sh second.sh`. When you run `sh second.sh`, you're running your script with your system's `sh` interpreter -- *not* the `ksh` interpreter that the script's shebang says it's written and tested for (and which the OS will automatically select if running `./second.sh`). If you can't change permissions to make it executable, at least run `ksh second.sh`, so you're manually invoking it with the same shell its shebang requests.